# T-SQL: Minimum number of characters to remove/replace so that one string is substring of another

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

I am looking to write a T-SQL Function that will return the minimum number of characters that needs to be removed from one of two strings so that string becomes a substring of the other.

The issue is, I am trying to determine how similar two last names are. Sometimes, people have multiple last names. In our client's database, we are finding that occasionally, we store both last names while the client only stores one, or the client stores both last names while we only store one. Since I cannot be sure which it will be, my idea was to start with one of the strings and see how many characters I needed to remove or replace to make one string a substring of the other. So, if the last name in our system was 'Johnson-Smith' while the last name in their system was 'Johnson', it would be zero characters removed so that 'Johnson' is a substring of 'Johnson-Smith'.

Alternately, if we misspelled the name 'Johnsen-Smith', we would need to remove at minimum 2 characters from 'Johnson' before it was a substring of 'Johnsen-Smith'. But, if we replace the 'e' with an 'o' character, it is one character replaced before Johnson is a substring of the modified string. So, the function should return 1.

Or if we have 'Johnson-Smit' and they have 'Smith', we need to remove only one character so that 'Smit' is a substring of 'Johnson-Smit'.

Does this type of distance have a name? I am familiar with Levenshtein and Hamming distance between strings, but neither proved particularly useful when comparing last names.

Does anyone have a function like this? I am thinking whatever I write will not be particularly efficient. Any suggestions on what to do to maximize efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oddity of "both" last names vs "one" last name is quite strange and probably nearly impossible to solve. But things like 'Johnsen-Smith' and 'Johnson-Smith' is quite easy using SOUNDEX. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql

```
select SOUNDEX('Johnsen-Smith')
    , SOUNDEX('Johnson-Smith')
    , SOUNDEX('Smith-Johnson') --provided this to demonstrate that the results are quite different.
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually kept working with it, and if I replace '-' with ' ' and grab the FirstWord and LastWord of the string, I can do the following check:

(DIFFERENCE(dbo.FirstWord(REPLACE(A.LastName,'-',' ')),dbo.FirstWord(REPLACE(B.LastName,'-',' ')))=4 
 OR DIFFERENCE(dbo.FirstWord(REPLACE(A.LastName,'-',' ')),dbo.LastWord(REPLACE(B.LastName,'-',' ')))=4 
 OR DIFFERENCE(dbo.LastWord(REPLACE(A.LastName,'-',' ')),dbo.FirstWord(REPLACE(B.LastName,'-',' ')))=4 
 OR DIFFERENCE(dbo.LastWord(REPLACE(A.LastName,'-',' ')),dbo.LastWord(REPLACE(B.LastName,'-',' ')))=4)

Comment: That check gives the data that I want. I just needed to create a simple FirstWord and LastWord function.

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FirstWord(@value nvarchar(4000))
BEGIN
   RETURN CASE CHARINDEX(' ',@value,1) WHEN 0 THEN @value ELSE LEFT(@value,CHARINDEX(' ',@value)-1) END
END

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LastWord(@value nvarchar(4000)) BEGIN RETURN CASE CHARINDEX(' ',@value,1) WHEN 0 THEN @value ELSE REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@value),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@value))-1)) END
END
GO